# Can login_required by applied to an entire app?

Tags: django

Is there a way I can apply the `login_required` decorator to an entire app?  When I say "app" I mean it in the django sense, which is to say a set of urls and views, not an entire project.

Comment: +1 - I was going to ask this same question.

Comment: ## As of Django 3+ ##
[See the solution here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64627298/6659365)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, you should use middleware.

Try to look through solutions which have some differences:

- http://www.djangosnippets.org/snippets/1179/ - with list of exceptions.
- http://www.djangosnippets.org/snippets/1158/ - with list of exceptions.
- http://www.djangosnippets.org/snippets/966/ - conversely with list of login required urls.
- http://www.djangosnippets.org/snippets/136/ - simplest.

Answer (score 3):

I clicked all the links in the anwsers, but they were all based on some kind of regular expressions. On Django 3+ you can do the following to restrict for a specific app:

- Declare `app_name="myapp"` in your app's `urls.py` (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/intro/tutorial03/#namespacing-url-names)
  (now all these urls should be called with there namespace "myapp:urlname")
- Create a `middleware.py` file in your app with this:

```py
from django.contrib.auth.views import redirect_to_login
from django.core.exceptions import ImproperlyConfigured

from django.urls import resolve


class LoginRequiredAccess:
   """All urls starting with the given prefix require the user to be logged in"""

   APP_NAME = 'myapp'

   def __init__(self, get_response):
       self.get_response = get_response

   def __call__(self, request):
       if not hasattr(request, 'user'):
           raise ImproperlyConfigured(
               "Requires the django's authentication middleware"
               " to be installed.")

       user = request.user
       if resolve(request.path).app_name == self.APP_NAME:  # match app_name defined in myapp.urls.py
           if not user.is_authenticated:
               path = request.get_full_path()
               return redirect_to_login(path)

       return self.get_response(request)
```

- Put `"myapp.middleware.LoginRequiredAccess"` in your `MIDDLEWARE` constant from `settings.py`
- Then in your main project `urls.py`

```py
urlpatterns = [
    path('foobar', include('otherapp.urls')),  # this will not be redirected
    path('whatever', include('myapp.urls')),  # all these urls will be redirected to login
]
```

On of the avantage of this method is it can still works with a root url path, e.g `path('', include('myapp.urls'))`, while the others will do an infinite redirect loop.

Answer (score 2):

As of Django 3+, you can set login_require() to an entire app by applying a middleware. Do like followings:

> Step 1: Create a new file anything.py in your yourapp directory and write the following:

```
import re
from django.conf import settings
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required

//for registering a class as middleware you at least __init__() and __call__()
//for this case we additionally need process_view() which will be automatically called by Django before rendering a view/template

class ClassName(object):
    
    //need for one time initialization, here response is a function which will be called to get response from view/template
    def __init__(self, response):
        self.get_response = response
        self.required = tuple(re.compile(url) for url in settings.AUTH_URLS)
        self.exceptions = tuple(re.compile(url)for url in settings.NO_AUTH_URLS)

    def __call__(self, request):
        //any code written here will be called before requesting response
        response = self.get_response(request)
        //any code written here will be called after response
        return response

    //this is called before requesting response
    def process_view(self, request, view_func, view_args, view_kwargs):
        //if authenticated return no exception
        if request.user.is_authenticated:
            return None
        //return login_required()
        for url in self.required:
            if url.match(request.path):
                return login_required(view_func)(request, *view_args, **view_kwargs)
        //default case, no exception
        return None
```

> Step 2: Add this anything.py to Middleware[] in project/settings.py like followings

```
MIDDLEWARE = [
    // your previous middleware
    'yourapp.anything.ClassName',
]
```

> Step 3: Also add the following snippet into project/settings.py

```
AUTH_URLS = (
    //disallowing app url, use the url/path that you added on mysite/urls.py (not myapp/urls.py) to include as your app urls
    r'/your_app_url(.*)$',
)
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking for [this snippet](http://www.djangosnippets.org/snippets/1179/), containing login-required [middleware](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/middleware/).

Answer (score 1):

This is an old question. But here goes:

[Django Decorator Include](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-decorator-include/1.0)

This is a substitute of `include` in URLConf. Pefect for applying `login_required` to an entire app.

Answer (score 0):

I'm wondering if there is any solution to make it works like this:

```
/app/app.py
class AppConfig(AppConfig):
    login_required = True

/project/urls.py
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'app/', include('app.urls', namespace='app'))
]

/common/middleare.py
def LogMiddleware(get_response):
    def middleware(request):
        # solution 1
        app = get_app(request)
        if app.login_required is True and request.is_authenticated is Fasle:
            return HttpResponseRedirect(redirect_url)
        # solution 2
        url_space = get_url_space(request.get_raw_uri())
        if url_space.namespace in ['app', 'admin', 'staff', 'manage'] and \
                request.is_authenticated is False:
            return HttpResponseRedirect(redirect_url)
```

I will check if there is any methoded to get the app or url name of a request. I think it looks prettier.