# Django 1.8: Password Protect Entire Project

Tags: django, django-settings

I have built my first Django App! It is built to help my business track inventory. As such, I would not like it to be publicly available.

Maybe someday I will set up multiple user accounts, etc, but for now I really just need a basic password gate to get it up and running.

Does anyone have any middleware that works for this? All the solutions that I am finding are pretty old and they do not seem to work with the latest version of Django.

Comment: what do you mean? middleware for what?

Comment: I've seen a few solutions with custom middleware that forces me to enter a password before I can access my site, but they are for older versions of Django.

Comment: Basic, you want the @login_required in all aplication?

Comment: Read this POST, maybe can fix it. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2164069/best-way-to-make-djangos-login-required-the-default

Comment: Thanks, that post is 5 years old already. I've been messing with it to try and get it working, but I keep getting stuck in a redirect loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found an answer that worked for me posted here:

[@login_required for multiple views](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23398393/login-required-for-multiple-views)

Make sure the `LOGIN_REQUIRED_URLS_EXCEPTIONS` path is correctly set to your login page.

Answer (score 1):

If you just need a single username/password couple, handling it directly via HTTP authentication in your webserver configuration will be the easiest way to achieve this. The benefits of this approach are:

1. You can set it up in 5 minutes: [example with nginx](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-http-authentication-with-nginx-on-ubuntu-12-10), example with [apache](https://wiki.apache.org/httpd/PasswordBasicAuth)
2. You don't have to write code you'll delete later
3. It will protect all your website, including static files, third-party apps, admin, etc.

Comment: Hah, I was avoiding this as I noobed out and went with Elastic Beanstalk to avoid learning absolutely anything about configuring webservers :D You are certainly right that it is the best way, and I will have to figure it out if there isn't an easy solution in Django.

Comment: You can probably end up with a working and clean solution using a middleware. However, knowing a little of webserver configuration will prove to be useful if you want to deploy your project somewhere else. Even if you don't become a sysadmin, understanding how to install and basically configure a web server is a useful skill.

Another option is to use django's built in auth system with a single username, and [decorate all your urls with the `login_required` decorator](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2307926/is-it-possible-to-decorate-include-in-django-urls-with-login-required)

Comment: It is a useful skill indeed, and its definitely on my list. I spent a few days trying to figure it out, and got completely frustrated, so I think I will have to have someone show me someday. That decorate URL option looks easy though! For some reason I thought you could only decorate views.

Comment: For setting up django with a webserver, I recommand nginx with [the following tutorial](http://michal.karzynski.pl/blog/2013/06/09/django-nginx-gunicorn-virtualenv-supervisor/). Basically, you can decorate views and single URLs. Using the link I gave in my previous comment, it seems there are way to decorate included URLs, which makes the task easier.

Comment: Thanks! I will bookmark that tutorial in case I find some time to try again. No luck getting this namespace trick to work so far, but I hope I can figure it out, because i have a ton of URLs.

Comment: The commented solution doesn't seem to be working out the box. Probably because it is 5 years old, like everything else I am finding.

Comment: I'm sorry to hear that. Another option could be to create a class based view mixin in which you decrate the dispatch method with `@login_required`. Then you make all your views inherit from this `LoginRequiredMixin`. But it only works if you use Class-Based-Views.

Comment: I might do that. I have quite a few views which was why I was avoiding having to flag them each individually, then remove them later if I changed my mind. It seems like a pretty clean solution, though.